# Lightroom keyboard shortcut to reset a picture's settings

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3

In Adobe Lightroom 3, is there a keyboard shortcut to reset a picture's settings? I'm looking for the equivalent of right-click on picture - Settings - Reset, within Develop.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-Shift+R resets all settings.  Cmd-Shift+R on a Mac.

Full list here:  [Adobe Lightroom 3 shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Lightroom/3.0/Using/WS18e2013dd74eab5fe275e2711d1b186fe9-8000.html)